# 'Rounding' lat/long coordinates to a 1km radius

Tags: geolocation, coordinates

I'm trying to figure out how to take a set of coordinates (ex: 35.7410435, -78.721417) and 'round' them, or simplify them, to a set of coordinates that is a set of coordinates with 1km in diameter around the given point.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is take geolocation data from users' in an app and send back data corresponding to their location. But for caching to be effective, I need to simplify the coordinates received to a specific number of decimal places so people standing 1000 feet from each other will get the same data, but by the time you get far enough away (I think 1km is enough), we will send them 'new' data.

I'm not sure if just rounding the coordinates received to the nearest 2 decimals is accurate or the correct thing to do. I imagine it's a big more involved than that. I've found different answers to calculate distance between to points, but nothing to get the coordinates of the circle that is 1km surrounding a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

```
public LatLng onePointFromCircle(LatLng centre, double radius) {
    Log.d(TAG + "one point", radius + "");
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378100.0;
    // Convert to radians.

    double lat = centre.latitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
    double lon = centre.longitude * Math.PI / 180.0;

    for (double t = 0; t <= Math.PI * 2; t += 0.3) {
        // y
        double latPoint = lat + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.sin(t)/ Math.cos(lat);
        // x
        double lonPoint = lon + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.cos(t)/ Math.cos(lat);

//      d=acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1-lon2))
        Log.d("latpoint",latPoint+"");
        Log.d("lonPoint",lonPoint+"");

        // saving the location on circle as a LatLng point
        LatLng point = new LatLng(latPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI, lonPoint
                * 180.0 / Math.PI);

        // here mMap is my GoogleMap object
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
        // now here note that same point(lat/lng) is used for marker as well
        // as saved in the ArrayList
        points.add(point);
    }


    return points.get(1);
}
```